# Структурные типы простых предложений

Tags: синтаксис

К какому структурному типу относятся эти предложения? (классификация Н.С. Валгиной)

1. Шансы равные.
2. Его фамилия Берман.
3. На плюще.
4. Тоже воспаление легких.
5. Джонси — уменьшительное от Джоанны.
6. Она вне опасности.
7. А теперь это легко.

P.S. Я понимаю, что это односоставные предложения, т.к. во всех отсутствует глагольная основа, но какой подтип односоставных? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: _Анастасия: Я понимаю, что это односоставные предложения..._  ===  Неправильно понимаете. Не все из приведённых Вами предложений односоставные.

Comment: И ещё: что значит "классификация Н.С. Валгиной"?

Comment: В учебнике "Синтаксис современного русского языка" авторства Н.С. Валгиной дается подобная структурная классификация, основанная на критерии членимости/нечленимости, вследствие чего в первом типе выделяются односоставные и двусоставные предложения, которые, в свою очередь, также имеют свои подтипы.

Comment: Если не все из этих предложений односоставные, тогда какие они? Я, к сожалению, не могу отнести их ни к одному типу(